# How to include and use Themes in wpf application

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes

I have to include themes to my wpf application and use them for look and feel of the windows(.xaml) and controls.

i tried to include the theme files like below code but it is throwing error.

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="\Themes\BureauBlack.xaml"/>
```

How to assign source path of a theme file which is assign Build action as Resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use MergedDictionaries:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic_UI/BlueColors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic_UI/KStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic_UI/KButtons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Generic_UI/KWindow.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: i gave theme file as resource. when i assigned to source it saying file not exist.

Comment: Does it work when you change the build action? Page for example?

Comment: Now its working. Overall theme is getting set. How to assign change the themes dynamically? like if the user select other themes it should change.

Comment: I am glad it is working. Now, this is another question. [You can have a look there first.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553184/let-the-user-change-the-resource-dictionnary)

Comment: Ohh do you want me to add another new question for Changing the theme during run time?

Comment: If my link doesn't answer to your question, yes I think it would be better to split different questions.